# Debugging third party AngularJS code

Tags: angularjs

We have an application running on server. We do have its source code. Error handling is written such that every time there is an exception a mail is sent to the administrator. My issue is, I am not aware which component / controller or file threw the exception.

The exception thrown is like:

```
StackTrace 
TypeError: Unable to get property 'length' of undefined or null reference at Anonymous function 
https://app.domain.com/js/app-controllers.9ebf94074df041eb.js:7:4669) 
at Anonymous function (https://app.domain.com/js/angular/angular.min.6a7688284ec564db.js:138:503) 
at e (https://app.domain.com/js/angular/angular.min.6a7688284ec564db.js:40:337) 
at Anonymous function (https://app.domain.com/js/angular/angular.min.6a7688284ec564db.js:44:375) 
at nrWrapper (https://app.domain.com/:20:15604)
```

There are tonnes of controllers in our code and we have no clue where this exception is thrown from! Is there a way to get to the root of such issues or the source of this exception?

The code has been written by a third party vendor and our inboxes are weeping.

Comment: You can try to unminify js and debug that code.

Comment: What's in app-controllers.9ebf94074df041eb.js:7:4669 and uses `.length`?

Comment: @Protozoid app-controller is a minifyd js file. I reckon it contains code for all the controllers at one place.

Comment: @MountainKing I can unminify it but the app code is separated in controllers.js and the minified has combined it at one place. It won't give an idea what code part calls the particular function.

Comment: @astm1982 Of course it's minified, concatenated, uglified, mangled and all the others ... but can you not navigate to line 7 column 4669 of this file? Look at the surrounding logic and try to recognise where that code is coming from ... it's clear that the issue is you've found a bug where you're not making sure that the element you're trying to get the length of is sometimes undefined